# How to set up classes to model one-to-many relationship with at least one object in the range set

Tags: c#, oop

Suppose you want to model the following situation using OOP.  You want to have a User class, an Album class, and a Photo class, such that

```
A User has 0 or more Albums
An Album has 1 or more Photos
```

Because I'm requiring an Album to have at least one Photo, I thought I should put a `List<Photo> photos` argument in the constructor of my Album class. However, this would assume that a list of Photo objects are created *before* the parent Album class is created. So, I cannot include a `Album parentAlbum` argument in the constructor of my Photo class like I was planning.

What is the best way for me to design so that each photo can reference it's parent album, but an album cannot be created without any photos?

Comment: I'm not so sure about the requirement that an album must have at least one photo. If I buy an empty photo album from the store, is it somehow not an album because it doesn't have any photos yet?

Comment: @musical_coder Don't worry the practicality of this example - it's just an example.

Comment: I guess it's more of a validation you would need to put to check if the Album is valid (strictly for one to many relationship) else 0-n or 1-n wont change your c# classes.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, I actually think you shouldn't reference the parent `Album` from a `Photo` instance, because: a) a photo doesn't need an album to exist, and b) you're limiting the re-usibility of `Photo` in the future. If you can come with a way to remove that reference, I'd do it. You could instead find the parent `Album` by searching through each `Album` you have, or better yet, create a dictionary of photos to albums.

That being said, I've definitely done similar things myself, because it makes coding a whole lot easier :) This doesn't set the parent `Album` in `Photo`'s constructor, but it's probably the next best thing:

```
class Album {

    public Album (List<Photo> photos)
    {
        if (photos.Count < 1)
        {
            throw new Exception("Album must have at least one photo.");
        }

        foreach (Photo thisPhoto in photos)
        {
            thisPhoto.setAlbum(this);
        }
    }

}
```